# Expression of type "List[int]" cannot be assigned to declared type "List[int | None]"

Tags: python, type-hinting

I would like to use the Pile type to hold lists of Cards and potentially None. I get this error on the list comprehension:

> Expression of type "List[int]" cannot be assigned to declared type
> "List[int | None]"

Here is my code:

```
Card: type = int
Pile: type = List[Optional[Card]]
deck: Pile = [i for i in range(1, 13)] * 12 + [0] * 18
```

What do I need to change about my list comprehension or my types to allow me to store both Cards and None?

Comment: For starters, `Card: type = int` seems wrong to me. If you want a type alias, don't type annotate it, that doesn't make sense. But *how do I reproduce this*?

Comment: The problem is with invariant containers. See http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#variance . This would work with a more flexible container type. `Pile = Sequence[Optional[int]]; deck; Pile = [i for i in range(1, 13)] *  * 12 + [0] * 18`

Comment: You get this error *from where*? Validating type annotations is not built-in functionality. If you are using, e.g. `mypy`, you should explicitly say so.

Comment: I'm relatively new to using type annotations in python so I'm not entirely sure what the good and bad practices are. For this project I was told to statically type everything, so I figured I should also annotate type aliases. I'm using Python 3.8.5 and Pylance in Visual Studio Code with typeCheckingMode set to basic

Comment: @flakes well, the container is less flexible (immutable) but the type allows for more flexible type inference :)

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I was able to solve my problem with list([i for i in range(1, 13)] *  * 12 + [0] * 18). I'm not entirely sure why this solution works though. What's the difference between a list comprehension and a list comprehension passed through the list constructor?